# Reaction kinetics exercise for hydrogen iodide synthesis

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, equilibrium, kinetics

The rate constant for the reaction of hydrogen with iodine is $\pu{2.45E-4 M-1 s-1}$ at 302 °C and $\pu{0.905 M-1 s-1}$ at 508 °C.

a. calculate the activation energy and Arrhenius preexponential factor for this reaction.

b. What is the value of the rate constant at 400 °C ?

---

I'm a bit confused because I get a negative value for the activation energy $E_a$

We have at 302 °C and 508 °C respectively
$$k_1 = \pu{2.45E-4 M-1 s-1}$$
$$k_2 = \pu{0.905 M-1 s-1}$$

We convert in Kelvin:
$$T_1 = 302 °C = 575.15 K $$
$$T_2 = 508 °C = 781.15 $$

The Arrhenius Equation is
$$\ln{k} = \ln{A} - \frac{E_a}{RT}$$

So we have
$$\ln{k_1} = \ln{A} - \frac{E_a}{RT_1}$$
$$\ln{k_2} = \ln{A} - \frac{E_a}{RT_2}$$

We want to solve for $E_a$. We subtract the second equation from the first:
$$\ln{k_1} - \ln{k_2} = - \frac{E_a}{R}(\frac{1}{T_1} - \frac{1}{T_2})$$

Solving for $E_a$, we get:
$$E_a = - R \times \frac{\ln{k_1} - \ln{k_2}}{\frac{1}{T_1} - \frac{1}{T_2}}$$

With $R = 8.314 J/mol K$, $T_1 = 575.15 K$, $T_2 = 781.15$, $k_1 = \pu{2.45E-4 M-1 s-1}$, $k_2 = \pu{0.905 M-1 s-1}$

(Link to [WolframAlpha calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=8.314%20*%20%28ln%282.45%20*%2010%5E%28-4%29%29%20-%20ln%280.905%29%29%2F%281%2F575.15%20-%201%2F781.15%29))

I get $E_a = 1.48948 \times 10^5 J/mol$

Then using the Arrhenius equation with $k_1$ or $k_2$:
$$A = k_1 \times \exp{\frac{E_a}{RT_1}}$$

(Link to [WolframAlpha calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2.45%20%2010%5E%7B-4%7D%20%20e%5E%28-148948%2F%288.314%20*%20575.15%29%29))

I get $A = \pu{8.26E9 M-1 s-1}$

But I'm confused, why the Activation Energy is negative ? Or did I miss something ? I checked all my calculations

EDIT: the error was due to a missing negative sign for $E_a = ...$. Now it makes more sense.

Comment: @Poutnik So how should I formulate the title ? "Why do I get a negative activation energy ?"

Comment: Instead of  $2.45 \times 10^{-4} M^{-1} s^{-1}$  ( `$2.45 \times 10^{-4} M^{-1} s^{-1}$` ), try $\pu{2.45E-4 M-1 s-1}$  (`$\pu{2.45E-4 M-1 s-1}$`). // As a simplified rule, only symbols for variables, physical(chemical) quantities or physical constants are in italic, all the rest is upright.

Comment: @Poutnik Thank you very much for your help. The error was in fact due to the missing negative sign. Now it makes more sense. I get $E_a = 148957$ J/mol. This gives an Arrhenius Pre-exponential factor of $\pu{8.26E9 M-1 s-1}$. For b), can we simply use the same formula with $T = 400$ ° C $= 673.15$ K as temperature ? This would give $\pu{8.26E9 \exp{(−148957​/(8.314×673.15))}}$ $= \pu{0.0228 M-1 s-1}$

Comment: @Poutnik Feel free to post an answer if you want (even just saying that it was due to the missing negative sign). I will accept it. Otherwise I will answer my own question later

Comment: It was nothing. But consider if "Always doublecheck signs in your calculations if you get weird results" is the good answer material.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mistake must have happened in your calculations, because, when I do them, I obtain :

ln$k_1 = - 8.314$;

ln$k_2 = - 0.100$;

ln$k_1$ - ln$k_2$ = $-8.314 + 0.100 = -8.214$

$\frac{1}{T_1} - \frac{1}{T_2}$ = $ \frac{1}{575} - \frac{1}{781} = 1.76·10^{-3} - 1.97·10^{-3} = - 0.21 ·10^{-3} $ K$^{-1}$

$E/R = \frac{-8.214}{-0.21·10^{-3} \mathrm{K}^{-1}} = + 39 100$ K.

$E = 39100$K$ · 8,314$ $\frac{J}{mol·K} = + 325.2$ kJ/mol

It is a positive result.